# Optional group for catching parentheses-enclosed text

Tags: regex

I'm a novice in regex but need to use it for a task and really appreciate if someone  could help me.

I have a string that might contain a parenthesis enclosed text at the end.

```
Something like these:
product1
product2 (enclosed text)
another product (some more enclosed text)
one more product
...
```

I need to separate the string in two groups.
The first one is the text before the parenthesis or the whole text if there's no parenthesis.

The second group is the parenthesis enclosed text and it should be optional.

I've tried `(.*)(\(.*\))?`  but the first group catches the whole string including parenthesis.

Comment: Would there ever be stray parentheses, or are you guaranteed one open, followed by one close parenthesis?

Answer (score 3):

If your language supports it:

```
(.*?)(\(.*\))?
```

The `*?` makes it a "reluctant" match (instead of a "greedy" one).

Otherwise, if you can guarantee there will never be any stray parenthesis:

```
([^\(\)]*)(\(.*\))?
```

Answer (score 1):

> <(.))(*/?) is the answer this is very simple